# Parse the text after using BS4, Python and Selenium

Tags: python, regex, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

after using my scrape script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://dyn.com/about/events/')
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
titles = [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all('p','pubdate')]
```

I have got the result that looks like:

> [u'\n\n\t\t\tWEBINAR: How To Expand Your Global Reach To China\xa0\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tOct 22, 2014\t\t\t\nspeak \n', u'\n\n\t\t\tLAUNCH Scale \u2013 San Francisco, CA\xa0\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tOct 23 - 24, 2014\t\t\t\nattend \n', u'\n\n\t\t\tAcquia Engage User Conference \u2013 Boston, MA\xa0\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tNov 3 - 5, 2014\t\t\t\nexhibitattend \n', u'\n\n\t\t\tCloud Expo \u2013 Santa Clara, CA\xa0\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tNov 4 - 6, 2014\t\t\t\nexhibit \n', u'\n\n\t\t\tThe Global Carrier Awards 2014 \u2013 Amsterdam\xa0\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tNov 4, 2014\t\t\t\n\n', u'\n\n\t\t\tWeb Summit \u2013 Dublin, Ireland\xa0\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tNov 4 - 6, 2014\t\t\t\nspeak \n', u'\n\n\t\t\tVelocity Europe \u2013 Barcelona, Spain\xa0\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tNov 17 - 19, 2014\t\t\t\nexhibit \n', u'\n\n\t\t\tNH/VT FIRST LEGO League Championship Event\xa0\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tDec 6, 2014\t\t\t\nspeak \n']

I am new to python, so could you suggest how can I get Event Name, Date, Event Type from this result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `stripped_strings` attribute to pluck out each component and construct a list of dictionaries, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://dyn.com/about/events/')
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

events = []
titles = soup.find_all('p','pubdate')
for title in titles:
    event = list(title.stripped_strings)
    events.append({
        'event_name': event[0],
        'event_date': event[1],
        'event_type': event[2:]    # there can be multiple event types so use a list
    })

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> for event in events:
...     pprint(event)
{'event_date': u'Oct 22, 2014',
 'event_name': u'WEBINAR: How To Expand Your Global Reach To China',
 'event_type': [u'speak']}
{'event_date': u'Oct 23 - 24, 2014',
 'event_name': u'LAUNCH Scale \u2013 San Francisco, CA',
 'event_type': [u'attend']}
{'event_date': u'Nov 3 - 5, 2014',
 'event_name': u'Acquia Engage User Conference \u2013 Boston, MA',
 'event_type': [u'exhibit', u'attend']}
{'event_date': u'Nov 4 - 6, 2014',
 'event_name': u'Cloud Expo \u2013 Santa Clara, CA',
 'event_type': [u'exhibit']}
{'event_date': u'Nov 4, 2014',
 'event_name': u'The Global Carrier Awards 2014 \u2013 Amsterdam',
 'event_type': []}
{'event_date': u'Nov 4 - 6, 2014',
 'event_name': u'Web Summit \u2013 Dublin, Ireland',
 'event_type': [u'speak']}
{'event_date': u'Nov 17 - 19, 2014',
 'event_name': u'Velocity Europe \u2013 Barcelona, Spain',
 'event_type': [u'exhibit']}
{'event_date': u'Dec 6, 2014',
 'event_name': u'NH/VT FIRST LEGO League Championship Event',
 'event_type': [u'speak']}
```

You might also want to split out the event name and event location splitting `event[0]` on the string `u' \u2013 '`

Comment: Looks exactly what i want, thank you! Could you advice there  is any way to put the event list to csv?

Comment: Take a look at [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). The multiple event types will need to be massaged into something that can be contained in a single field (e.g. `'|'.join(d.event_type)`), or figure out a way to have extra CSV fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `\n` and `\t` in the ouput

for example you can use `re.sub` function to replace.

```
import re

for val in titles:
     print re.sub("[\n\t]", "", val)
```

would produce output as

```
    WEBINAR: How To Expand Your Global Reach To China Oct 22, 2014speak
    LAUNCH Scale – San Francisco, CA Oct 23 - 24, 2014attend
    Acquia Engage User Conference – Boston, MA Nov 3 - 5, 2014exhibitattend
    Cloud Expo – Santa Clara, CA Nov 4 - 6, 2014exhibit
    The Global Carrier Awards 2014 – Amsterdam Nov 4, 2014
    Web Summit – Dublin, Ireland Nov 4 - 6, 2014speak
    Velocity Europe – Barcelona, Spain Nov 17 - 19, 2014exhibit
    NH/VT FIRST LEGO League Championship Event Dec 6, 2014speak
```

The function

```
re.sub("[\n\t]", "", val)
```

replaces `\n` and `\t` wihth empty string.

Comment: thanks, this solution is good to make content readable, but i wanted to group the data